# Mapping Scala Slick objects to/from Java POJOs

Tags: java, scala, slick, pojo, orika

I'd like to use Scala Slick in my backend code and I also have requirement to support a legacy web service API that needs to expose my domain model as normal Java POJOs.

Are there some nice object mapper libraries or other solutions for this task other than writing manual mapping code? I have used Orika object mapper before (in Java only) and it has  some nice features like mapping properties with the same name by default, ability to provide custom mappers by types..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extensible Slick code generator to generate mappings to your existing classes instead of new case classes. You probably would want to `enable = false` some of the inner classes of the code generator and override the EntityType to generate simple factories instead of case classes. See http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/code-generation.html

I'll speak about the code generator at Scala Days 2014, which will probably be helpful with this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [annotating your Scala objects](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-javabeans-beanproperty-annotation) with `@BeanProperty` would be helpful.

> This is pretty cool; just by adding the @BeanProperty tag to your
>   class fields, the get and set (getter and setter) JavaBean methods
>   will be generated for you automatically.

I don't believe it'll handle converting between Java/Scala collections (e.g. between their relative concepts of `Map`/`List` etc.) but that in itself would implement some copying of collections, which may not be intuitive in itself.